# IntelliJ Can't Extract a Constant using Keyboard Shortcut Ctrl+Alt+C

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have never been able to use `Ctrl+Alt+C` to extract a constant in IntelliJ. As a work around I've been using the `Shift+Ctrl+A` -> 'Constant...'. Maybe there is a windows shortcut that is intercepting it and preventing IntelliJ from executing it? I'm at a loss and its mildly annoying that I can't use it.

Comment: I assume you're using a standard keyboard layout & latin language? Do any other shortcuts fail?  I don't believe there's a default windows shortcut that overrides this one, I've just tested with Windows (UK keyboard) and it works OK.

Comment: I'm using a English US keyboard (windows) and the default IntelliJ keyboard shortcuts. I can't think of any other shortcuts that fail, I can do `Ctrl+Alt+v` (variables) `Ctrl+Alt+m` (methods) `Ctrl+Alt+n` (inline variable/method) and `Ctrl+Alt+f` (fields) with no problem. Just not the constants.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug. I found [other bugs around this functionality](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=extract+constant+windows) but nothing that sounds like your issue.  Maybe best to take a look to see if one of these bugs matches yours, and if not raise a new one.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look.

Comment: Do you have intel graphics card? I know I had problems, because Intel HD Graphics drivers would intercept shortcuts even if disabled. I went to its control panel (from desktop's popup menu) and changed all shortcuts to some like ctrl + shift + num(7)

Comment: @Trisha I was unable to find anything related to my issue so I've created a new issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145550.

Comment: @wasyl Good idea, but I'm using an AMD Radeon HD 7470, and I can't find any keyboard shortcuts related to it. I did try to see if there were any other applications which might have keyboard shortcuts defined, but I wasn't able to find any.

Comment: same problem but in mac. fn + option + command worked for me